# Decompressing an LZO stream in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, stream, bigdata, lzo

I have a number of LZO-compressed log files on Amazon S3, which I want to read from PHP. The AWS SDK provides a nice [StreamWrapper](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/TxKV69TBGSONBU/Amazon-S3-PHP-Stream-Wrapper) for reading these files efficiently, but since the files are compressed, I need to decompress the content before I can process it.

I have installed the [PHP-LZO extension](https://github.com/adsr/php-lzo) which allows me to do `lzo_decompress($data)`, but since I'm dealing with a stream rather than the full file contents, I assume I'll need to consume the string one LZO compressed block at a time. In other words, I want to do something like:

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory( $myAwsCredentials );
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();

$stream = fopen("s3://my_bucket/my_logfile", 'r');

$compressed_data = '';
while (!feof($stream)) {
    $compressed_data .= fread($stream, 1024);

    // TODO: determine if we have a full LZO block yet
    if (contains_full_lzo_block($compressed_data)) {

        // TODO: extract the LZO block
        $lzo_block = get_lzo_block($compressed_data);

        $input = lzo_decompress( $lzo_block );
        // ...... and do stuff to the decompressed input
    }

}
fclose($stream);
```

The two `TODO`s are where I'm unsure what to do:

1. Inspecting the data stream to dtermine whether I have a full LZO block yet
2. Extracting this block for decompression

Since the compression was done by Amazon (s3distCp) I don't have control over the block size, so I'll probably need to inspect the incoming stream to determine how big the blocks are -- is this a correct assumption?

(ideally, I'd use a custom StreamFilter directly on the stream, but I haven't been able to find anyone who has done that before)

Comment: what about using some system command to decompress the lzo file instead of implementing decompression from scratch under PHP? I searched for php lzo libraries and found none.

Comment: Decompressing through a system command would work just fine -- if someone could post a working example of that, I'd happily accept that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok executing a command via PHP can be done in many different ways, something like:

```
$command = 'gunzip -c /path/src /path/dest';
$escapedCommand = escapeshellcmd($command);
system($escapedCommand);
```

or also

```
shell_exec('gunzip -c /path/src /path/dest');
```

will do the work.
Now it's a matter of what command to execute, under Linux there's a nice command line tool called lzop which extracts orcompresses lzop files.

You can use it via something like:

```
lzop -dN sources.lzo
```

So you final code might be something as easy as:

```
shell_exec('lzop -dN s3://my_bucket/my_logfile');
```

Comment: That looks promising. I'll give it a shot tomorrow!